# PrimeFaces, p:media audio file playback error

Tags: jsf, audio, primefaces, jsf-2, inputstream

i have issue with playback of some mp3 files.

Issue:
While mp3 is playing there is no way to go back on player slider, it will just continue without stopping. This seems to happend only with bigger files.

File is located on remote FTP server.
file is saved as InputStream:

```
InputStream out=null;    
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ftpClient.retrieveFile(path+"/"+ff.getName(), outputStream);
out = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
return out;
```

then i will save it as DefaultStreamContent:

```
byte[] b=IOUtils.toByteArray(is);

ftpUploadController.getFtpClient().sendCommand("NOOP");

is = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
media = new DefaultStreamedContent(is, "audio/mpeg");

is.close();
```

and my XHTML media file:

```
<p:media id="media" cache="true" value="#{stream}"   player="quicktime"  height="60" width="200" >
    <f:param name="enablejavascript" value="true"/>
</p:media>
```

found similiar issue of Primefaces forum:
http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8562
but no one helped.

I'm using PrimeFaces 6.0

Anyone have so sugestions ? Thank you.